# removing groups by group number of rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I need to remove all tokens where the number of rows in the group are less than 3.

Dataframe:-

|  | token | active |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 58 | 1 |
| 1 | 58 | 8 |
| 2 | 63 | 5 |
| 3 | 63 | 9 |
| 4 | 63 | 0 |
| 5 | 97 | 6 |
| 6 | 97 | 1 |

I filtered groups having less than 3 rows, but how to remove those groups from main dataframe?

```
c_df = df.groupby('token').agg('count')
sc_df = c_df.loc[c_df['active'] < 3]
print(sc_df)
```

Current result:-

| token | active |
| --- | --- |
| 58 | 2 |
| 97 | 2 |

Comment: Please initialize `df` so that this is a running script. "where rows are less than 3" ... is that supposed to be "where active is less than 3"? Or where there are fewer than 3 equal token values in a row? Each row in the dataframe is called "row" so you need to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use slicing:

```
df = df[df.groupby('token')['active'].transform('count').ge(3)]
```

output:

```
   token  active
2     63       5
3     63       9
4     63       0
```

Answer (score 2):

Let us try `filter`

```
out = df.groupby('token').filter(lambda x : len(x)>=3)
Out[24]: 
   token  active
2     63       5
3     63       9
4     63       0
```

Comment: nice one, I had forgotten this method ;) +1

Comment: @mozway same as your solution +1

Comment: in the production dataframe, there will be 200 different tokens and each token having 30 rows (may be more than that), so dataframe will be of total 6K+ rows. Which solution will be preferable there? (btw both solution worked [+1], will be accepting the solution which will be preferred on large data)

Comment: @yaliga well testing speed is really data dependent. *You* only have the perfect dataset, why don't you try and tell us? A test on your sample data gives BENY's solution a slight margin, same test on 10000 times the samples give mine ~2 times faster. So you tell us with yours ;)

Comment: Rows tested:- `142080` ,  Beny:- *0:00:00.343801* & Mozway:- ***0:00:00.156282***